# Celery in multidocker worker application

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, rabbitmq, celery

Project structure

```
app/
    flask_app/
        app.py
        Dockerfile
    worker_type_1/
        worker_core/
            core.py
        celery.py
        Dockerfile
    worker_type_3/
        worker_core/
            core.py
        celery.py
        Dockerfile
    worker_type_3/
        worker_core/
            core.py
        celery.py
        Dockerfile
```

Each worker performs a different task. Tasks are summitted by flask_app.
Dockerfile runs celery worker.

I have few questions regarding this.

1. Is this a correct way to structure the project?
2. Where worker listened queues should be defined?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're breaking the workers up that way, instead of letting every worker run any task that gets scheduled?

Comment: I am planning to deploy it on kubernetes, so the reason is to be able to scale each worker separately.

Comment: I would use a single codebase but use [Celery Task Routing](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) to have the different works pick up different tasks, rathe than separating things out like you're currently doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than taking this approach I would build a single codebase and container that was configured with environmental variables.

Since you want to have different "classes" of workers for autoscaling purposes I would use [Celery Task Routing](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) to push your tasks to the appropriate queues.

When deploying your workers celery has an argument to define which queue to work off of, so you'd only need to change the startup command for the worker in your container. Your best bet here is to make it an environmental variable so your provisioning scripts can easily launch it.

```
celery -A proj worker -Q $QUEUE_NAME
```

The benefit of this is a simpler build, debug, and deploy process.

Comment: I was thinking of having just a single codebase, it is easier. The only problem I see is the scalling, i.e. if suddenly I will have a high load on `worker_type_1`. Kubernetes would allow to spawn additional pods. That is my main concern regarding this.

Comment: I think that problem is solved by using different queues and the task routing. That would allow you to segment your tasks, and the autoscaling around it, without needing separate container images for each worker.